# Ignore ng-click when opening dropdown

Tags: html, angularjs, html-select, angularjs-ng-click, angularjs-ng-change

I have a list with options, which I loop into a select with `ng-options`. Then I would like to call a function, when I click on one of the options. I tried it first with `ng-change`, but the problem I had is, that I can't detect a change, when I clicked on the same option twice in a row, so it just calls the function when I click the first time on it. Than I tried it with `ng-click`. The problem now was, that it also detects the click, when I open the dropdown. So it calls then also the function. Is there a way, to ignore the click when I open the dropdown and just detect it, when a click on a option? I also tried to give the `$event` as parameter in my function and check there, if the option was clicked, but I didn't found the solution. This is my code:

```
<select ng-options="option as option.name for option in myOptionsList" ng-model="currentOption" ng-click="myFunction($event)"></select>
```

My list:

```
myOptionsList = [
    {id: 1, name: 'Option 1'},
    {id: 2, name: 'Option 2'},
    {id: 3, name: 'Option 3'}
];
```

My function:

```
myFunction(event) {
    console.log(event);
    console.log('Print this if only option was clicked!');
}
```

Any ideas how to ignore `ng-click` when I just open the dropdown and just detect it when `option` was clicked, or how to detect `ng-change` when the selected `option` was clicked again? Thanks.

=======================================================================

**EDIT - EXAMPLE:**
I have a window, where I can filter a list. This window I open with a option in my select. So when I open the select, it opens the window. Now imagine, that I set some filter criterias, close the window and my list is filtered now. The option, which opens the filter is still selected. Now I see, that I have to change my filter criterias a little bit, so I open the dropdown again, and click a second time on the option to open the window, but id doesn't work, because it's still selected and ng-change didn't detect any changes in the select. How can I force this:

```js
angular.module("myApp", []).controller("myController", function($scope) {
  $scope.currentOption;
  $scope.showWindow = false;

  $scope.myOptions = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'This opens the window'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Option 2'
  }, {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Option 3'
  }];

  $scope.showOption = function() {
    if ($scope.currentOption.id == 1) {
      $scope.showWindow = true;
    }
    console.log($scope.currentOption);
  }

  $scope.closeWindow = function() {
    $scope.showWindow = false;
  }
});
```

```css
.filterWindow {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
  z-index: 100;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <select ng-options="option as option.name for option in myOptions" ng-change="showOption()" ng-model="currentOption"></select>

  <div ng-if="showWindow" class="filterWindow">
    <button ng-click="closeWindow()">Close</button>
    Some filter criterias...
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use This Instead:

```
<select ng-options="option as option.name for option in myOptionsList" 
       ng-model="selectedItem" ng-change="update()">
</select>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.myOptionsList = [
    {id: 1, name: 'Option 1'},
    {id: 2, name: 'Option 2'},
    {id: 3, name: 'Option 3'}
];
  $scope.update = function() {
    console.log($scope.selectedItem)
  }
```

Here is the Working JS FIDDLE link: http://jsfiddle.net/jazibbashir/G8S32/1855/

==========================================================================

**New Requirment Solution**

Just replace ng-change with ng-click.

```js
angular.module("myApp", []).controller("myController", function($scope) {
  $scope.currentOption;
  $scope.showWindow = false;

  $scope.myOptions = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'This opens the window'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Option 2'
  }, {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Option 3'
  }];

  $scope.showOption = function() {
    if ($scope.currentOption.id == 1) {
      $scope.showWindow = true;
    }
    console.log($scope.currentOption);
  }

  $scope.closeWindow = function() {
    $scope.showWindow = false;
  }
});
```

```css
.filterWindow {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
  z-index: 100;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <select ng-options="option as option.name for option in myOptions" ng-click="showOption()" ng-model="currentOption"></select>

  <div ng-if="showWindow" class="filterWindow">
    <button ng-click="closeWindow()">Close</button>
    Some filter criterias...
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, but this seems not working as I would like... Open you're console, than open the select choose 'Option 1', it will be printed... Than again open the console and select again the 'Option 1', which is already selected... nothing happens and the functions isn't called? But I would like to call the function also when I click twice in a row on the same option...

Comment: Unable to produce your issue everything working perfect at my end
check out  this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/jazibbashir/G8S32/1855/

or if you want Double Click than define angular directive which trigger function on double click.

Tell me if you need mere help related to double click directive etc.

Comment: Hi, please look at my edit (the example with the code snippet) and read the description of it.... This is what I want to do... You can simulate it there...I hope it's clear enough now.. :) thanks

Comment: @MrBuggy Thanks for explanation.
i updated my answer according to your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

We can achieve this with little hack.

Example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/acmph4am/).

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.myOptionsList = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Option 1'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Option 2'
  }, {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Option 3'
  }];
  $scope.update = function($event) {
    if ($event.screenX == 0)
      console.log('click on OPTION');
    else
      console.log('click on SELECT');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <select ng-options="option as option.name for option in myOptionsList" ng-model="selectedItem" ng-click="update($event)">
  </select>
  {{selectedItem.id}} {{selectedItem.name}}
</div>
```

Comment: What does screenX actually do? Cheers

Comment: During testing, I found that if the event `ng-click` happened on **<option>**, the mouse cursor `screenX` coordinates are set to **0**.

Comment: Hi, I've tested it also in IE, there is always "click on SELECT" in the console (also when I click on an option). So this solution does not work on every browser...But thanks...

Comment: In any case, the native event `onclick` does not work on the **<option>**. I do not think that `angular` will be able to do cross-browser.

Comment: Angular Support:

=> Opera 15+
=> Internet Explorer: 9+
=> Firefox, Safari, and Google Chrome

Comment: Versions 1.2 and later of AngularJS do not support Internet Explorer versions 6 or 7.
Versions 1.3 and later of AngularJS dropped support for Internet Explorer 8.